# Is exp map a global diffeo for the Lie group of positive smooth functions on a manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

As I understand it, for the Lie group of positive real numbers under multiplication, the exp map from its Lie algebra as a vector space of all real numbers to this group is a global diffeomorphism.

I am tempted to think that the same conclusion would hold for the infinite-dimensional Lie group (in the IHL sense, if appropriate) of positive real-valued functions on a (compact) manifold under multiplication whose Lie algebra is the vector space of all real-valued functions. Assume proper Sobolev spaces are used, just for the peace of mind.

Is this true? If so, how to see it; if not, what goes wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This map is obviously a bijection. Beyond that, you have to spell out precisely what topology and what manifold structure is used in your question ("proper Sobolev spaces" does not cut it).

Comment: Do you mean "in the ILH sense" (inverse limit Hilbert) instead of IHL?